# Write a message to a log

Tags: c#, beginner, file, logging

I have started to read Robert C. Martin Clean Code book.

To learn and gain more expreiences I wrote a single Log class. So I want some suggestions to improve this code..
This is a part of the Log class:

```
public class FileLogger : ILog
{
    private string directoryPath = string.Empty;
    private string fileName = string.Empty;

    public FileLogger(string logDirectoryPath, string logFileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(logDirectoryPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(logDirectoryPath), "Write some error message...");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(logFileName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(logFileName), "Write some error message...");
        }

        this.directoryPath = logDirectoryPath;
        this.fileName = logFileName;
    }

    public void LogMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                if (!LogDirectoryExists(directoryPath))
                {
                    CreateLogDirectory(directoryPath);
                }

                WriteToLogFile(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Catch exception, do something...
        }
    }

    private bool LogDirectoryExists(string logDirectoryPath)
    {
        return Directory.Exists(logDirectoryPath);
    }

    private void CreateLogDirectory(string logDirectoryPath)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(logDirectoryPath);
    }

    private void WriteToLogFile(string message)
    {
        using (var logFile = new FileStream(Path.Combine(directoryPath,fileName), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var logFileWriter = new StreamWriter(logFile))
            {
                logFileWriter.Write(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote 3 different function to write a message to a log. I try to use SRP and Command Query Separation, but I don't sure this is a good in this way. Maybe there are another problems with this code, example naming or variable declarations.

Comment: Use `Path.Combine` instead of manual path parts concatenation with backslash. Also there is no necessity to specify types of variable explicitly in your `using`s, you can use `var`. Field names (`DirectoryPath`, `FileName`) shouldn't start with uppercase letter. And check `message` on `null` in `LogMessage`.

Comment: Thanks. To check message on null, if I think right I had to write a function for this and calls this in LogMessage, due to SRP?
Sorry if I ask "small things", but I want to understand this well.

Comment: You can check an argument directly in `LogMessage`, it is absolutely OK. Also check `logDirectoryPath` and `logFileName` in constructor.

Comment: Based on your suggestions , I rewrite.

Comment: You should use `ArgumentNullException` or `ArgumentException` in your case instead of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Rule of thumb is to use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` only for number arguments. Inspect standard methods and classes to learn what exception to throw in particular case. Also use `nameof` operator to pass parameter name to constructor of an exception class.

Comment: OK, I undertand. I updated it.

Comment: @Maxim please write an answer. Comments are not for reviewing code

Comment: @NewbieUser please do not post the same code multiple times or otherwise it's not clear what is the latest version. For as long as there are no answers you are free to update your question and your code. It's not necessary to copy/paste it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion in comments your code became much better.

Also if `directoryPath` and `fileName` will not be changed after initialization in constructor you can define these fields as `readonly`:

```
private readonly string directoryPath = string.Empty;
private readonly string fileName = string.Empty;
```

This code

> ```
> using (var logFile = new FileStream(Path.Combine(directoryPath,fileName), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
> {
>     using (var logFileWriter = new StreamWriter(logFile))
>     {
>         logFileWriter.Write(message);
>     }
> }
> ```

can be replaced with

```
File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName), message);
```

Also `ArgumentException`'s constructor takes `message` as first argument and `paramName` as second, so you need to call it like this:

```
throw new ArgumentException("Write some error message...", nameof(logDirectoryPath));
```

Comment: Because the constructor initializes those fields, they shouldn't be initialized to `string.Empty` either. It's redundant.